# How to combine these two App Script formulas?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

If both columns <kbd>E</kbd> and <kbd>K</kbd> have value in them → then run the function in the <kbd>column G</kbd>.

As a regular Sheets formula, it looks like this (it works):

```
=if(not(isblank({$E12,$K12})),$K12*$E12," ")
```

I need App Script that does the same.

Why do I need a Script instead of regular formula? Because Arrayformula doesn't allow me to write in the same column, I will need this same script for other similarly made formulas.

1)This one is for checking if cells are blank (E12 and K12):

```
var isCellBlank = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Copy of Produkti').getRange().isBlank();

if(!isCellBlank) {
    iSheet.getRange().setValues();
}
```

2)This one is for the function I want to run:

```
function FillFormulas() {   

var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Copy of Produkti');   

var lastRow = spreadsheet.getLastRow();   

spreadsheet.getRange("G4").setFormula("=if(not(isblank({$E12,$K12})),$K12*$E12," ")");   
var fillDownRange = spreadsheet.getRange(4,7,(lastRow-1));   spreadsheet.getRange("G4").copyTo(fillDownRange); 

}
```

Function onEdit(e) I have in a different file.

Can you help me fill in the first part of the Script (isCellBlank - get.Range i guess)?

And how to combine these two scripts, so that it does the same as regular sheet formula, just for the whole column (like Arrayformula)?

Answer (score 0):

If you could add a hidden column before G you could follow this approach I've explained in this other post:

You could sort it out with hidden columns, and values that expand to the next column in which you'd like to have your result or input your value.
Instead a formula: `=B3/B4` you'd have `={",",B3/B4}`

So, if you manually insert a value in the right column, the formula in left column won't expand. As an example I've created a very dummy calculator of sides and hypothenuse. In B1 (column B in red would be hidden) I have:

```
={"","Res: "&(C3^2-C2^2)^(1/2)}
```

And so on in the next rows. In this picture I've inserted manual values in C1 and C2, so C3 has a result:

[[image]]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXdTl.jpg)

And another example in another row:

[image]

You can test it out here and the extrapolate it to your formulas,
(I've erased the part with "Res. " so the result is an actual number, it was just for easier view in my examples):

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZaEEGWtLU-LXBmg-xy80Ps_biuYhb8WxZBs0g1tGE00/edit?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Thank you for your comment, it works, but I have another question then - how can I make this an Arrayformula? I need it for the whole column, last year we had data for 500 rows. I tried adding Arrayformula at the beginning and before multiplication - not working. I tried like this ={"",if(not(isblank({$E12:E1020,$L12:L1020})),$L12:L1020*$E12:E1020," ")}, but it also does this only for one row.